# Camel 2.X.X : Put property file(.cfg) in sub-directory of etc directory to load property with cm:property-placeholder

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

blueprint.xml

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="client.service"
    update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="URI"
            value="https://blabla/" />
        <cm:property name="ConnectionTimeout" value="18000" />
        <cm:property name="ResponseTimeout" value="10000" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="configData"
    class=" com.myproject.ConfigurationData">
    <property name="URI" value="${URI}" />
    <property name="ConnectionTimeout" value="${ConnectionTimeout}" />
    <property name="ResponseTimeout" value="${ResponseTimeout}" />
</bean>
```

Here in default case, i need to put client.service.cfg file in ${karaf.home}/etc directory but
I want client.service.cfg file in sub-directory of etc directory. For example ${karaf.home}/etc/client1/

Comment: On top of my head I dont think karaf supports sub folders in its etc directory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I updated blueprint.xml with bean in question. Is there any other way to do this type of configuration ?.

Comment: I can read sub folders in its etc directory but for that i need to update value of felix.fileinstall.dir in config.properties in etc folder itself. For example. **felix.fileinstall.dir    = ${karaf.base}/etc,${karaf.base}/etc/client1**. But i dont want to do this configuration at Servicemix, instead i want to configure my bundle to read property from specified folder.

Comment: You would need to configure the felix file installed to scan for those sub dirs, i think its configured for etc only. Check the various SMX config files

Comment: You are right. As i mentioned in previous comment. _"felix.fileinstall.dir = ${karaf.base}/etc,${karaf.base}/etc/client1. But i don't want to do this configuration at Servicemix's file, instead i want to configure my bundle to read property from specified folder."_.

Comment: But i don't want to do this configuration at Servicemix's file, instead i want to **configure my bundle** to read property from specified subfolder in etc. By this way i will not require to update _config.properties_ every time i add new sub-folder in etc folder.

Comment: And that is not possible today!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, We decided to change the configuration of servicemix to read the configuration (.cfg) file from multiple locations by following way.

Update value of property felix.fileinstall.dir in config.properties file in etc folder itself. For example.

```
 felix.fileinstall.dir = ${karaf.base}/etc,${karaf.base}/etc/client1
```

So, now servicemix will read and dynamically reload property from etc as well as atc/client1 directories.